# IE8 Back button + https:// security error

Tags: html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, https

Unfortunately, I can't provide a usable test case, since my development servers are not publicly available, however, I've been getting a bug in IE, where any time I click the back button, I get an https:// security violation error on an image that I am serving up from my own server, correctly labeled as https://

It also kills any javascript from executing, which is odd behavior, as other https:// warning did not do this.

Could anyone point me in the right direction to address this?

Comment: The solution is not to use IE:) Otherwise can you please show us a Fiddler log, the security violation error and more info on the javascript not executing

Comment: Do you have some very strict session control or something? This may occur if you have a login script, e.g., that links to non-secure resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to leave some documentation, the reason for this is that IE8 doesn't like relative paths in css background-images.

I have no idea why this is, but if you use an absolute path including the https://, this will stop happening.